# Calculate moving direction of an object

Tags: math

Given a multidimensional space and a target position and velocities of the moving object, how to determine if the object is going in the right direction, therefore approaching the target?

For example, if I have a 3-D space, I have a desired target position of [0, 0, 100], I know my moving object is going at a velocity of [1, 2, 4], how to calculate the discrepancy between the moving direction and the desired direction?

Please note I am not using unity

Comment: Do you have the moving object position?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: oh well, yes. it is a math and physics question. however to say it has nothing to do with programming is not exactly right. This is one of the important questions I need to solve in my most recent project (in machine learning). I also did not know that math questions are not welcome in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you've asked is more of a math question than a programming question. I believe it's still on-topic, but that means we'll have more of a mathematical solution. I'm assuming you have very little in the way of math functions at your disposal.

## Setup

(Note: This is going to involve vectors. If a variable is bold, I'm treating it like a vector.)

So, we want to reach **P<sub>f</sub>** = [0, 0, 100] units. We are at **P<sub>i</sub>** = [x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>, z<sub>i</sub>] units. We have a velocity of **v** = [1, 2, 4] units/frame.

If I understand correctly, we want to know two things:

1. Will we hit the target?
2. If not, how far off are we? (That is: what's the angle between where we are going and where we want to go?)

## Execution

We only need to solve the second part, and then we can figure out the first part based on that solution. (I'll get to solving the first part on its own later.)

For solving the second part, our best friend is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)! Your problem revolves around vectors, and the dot product can tell us how closely related two vectors are.

First, we'll need our two <strike>victims</strike> vectors. We already have one: **v**, the current velocity. Then, assuming we have **P<sub>i</sub>**, we can find the desired path, which is the path between **P<sub>i</sub>** and **P<sub>f</sub>**. I'll call this **s<sub>f</sub>** = **P<sub>f</sub>** - **P<sub>i</sub>**.

(For lack of a character to use for dot product, dot(**m**, **n**) will stand for the dot product of **m** and **n**.)

First, we'll start with one of the definitions of the dot product presented by the Wikipedia article:

(Equ 1)
dot(**v**, **s<sub>f</sub>**) = ||**v**|| ||**s<sub>f</sub>**|| cos(Ɵ)

> Quick note: The double bars mean [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)#Vector_spaces), which is equal to the sum of the squares of the vector components, or
>   ||**v**|| = sqrt(v<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + v<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> + v<sub>z</sub><sup>2</sup>)
>   To make this easier to work with, I'll assume that we've calculated the magnitudes ahead of time, so we can leave them in our equations.

Anyway, (Equ 1) isn't enough! We don't know Ɵ or dot(**v**, **s<sub>f</sub>**), so what now?

There's another definition of dot product in that first Wikipedia article. It goes like this:

(Equ 2)
dot(**v**, **s<sub>f</sub>**) = v<sub>x</sub>s<sub>fx</sub> + v<sub>y</sub>s<sub>fy</sub> + v<sub>z</sub>s<sub>fz</sub>

We know all of those values! And, since (Equ 1) is equal to (Equ 2), we can combine these two equations. This gets us:

||**v**|| ||**s<sub>f</sub>**|| cos(Ɵ) = v<sub>x</sub>s<sub>fx</sub> + v<sub>y</sub>s<sub>fy</sub> + v<sub>z</sub>s<sub>fz</sub>

Aaand shuffling things around...

cos(Ɵ) = (v<sub>x</sub>s<sub>fx</sub> + v<sub>y</sub>s<sub>fy</sub> + v<sub>z</sub>s<sub>fz</sub>) / (||**v**|| ||**s<sub>f</sub>**||)

...or...
Ɵ = cos<sup>-1</sup>( (v<sub>x</sub>s<sub>fx</sub> + v<sub>y</sub>s<sub>fy</sub> + v<sub>z</sub>s<sub>fz</sub>) / (||**v**|| ||**s<sub>f</sub>**||) )

And that's our final equation!

## *CELEBRATE!!!*

Well...now we got to actually use it. If you aren't the math type (or, if my explanation was terrible and I lost you somewhere), I'll boil down what this last equation can do for us.

The result of the last equation determines the angle that we are off by. It will range from 0 degrees to 180 degrees (or 0 radians to π radians). 0 degrees means that we are heading directly towards the target, while 180 degrees means that we are heading directly away it.

If either ||**v**|| or ||**s<sub>f</sub>**|| are zero, **then this equation is invalid**. This makes sense; if we're already on top of our target, the distance to travel is zero and there's no angle to calculate. At the same time, if the velocity is zero, then we aren't going anywhere and cannot calculate the angle. Note that a vector's magnitude is only zero if *all* of its values are zero, so this is an easy check.

## Math is good and all, but...

I'll put this in terms should look more familiar to coders.

```c
struct Vector3 { double x, y, z; }

float CalcMagnitude(Vector3 v)
{
    return sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z)
}

float CalcAngle(Vector3 currentPos, Vector3 targetPos, Vector3 velocity)
{
    Vector3 targetDir = targetPos - currentPos

    if( `all the values in targetDir are zero`
        or `all the values in velocity are zero` )
    {
        // We can't really return anything valid. Maybe return
        // -1 or throw an exception or something
    }

    // Calculate the dot product
    double numerator =
        velocity.x * targetDir.x
        + velocity.y * targetDir.y
        + velocity.z * targetDir.z

    double denominator = CalcMagnitude(velocity) * CalcMagnitude(targetDir)

    return acos(numerator / denominator)
}
```

Comment: so is this essentially a question of finding the angle between the targetDir and the velocity?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. With geometry, it looks simple (it's a pair of vectors), but doing it with the components alone takes some more steps.